# why is my rigging making my model bigger?

Tags: rigging

i'm trying to make a rig for a model but when i set parent with automatic weights is scales the actual model to the point i cant zoom out enough to see above the knees. I really need help with this.

Comment: maybe you've scaled your bones in Pose mode? In that case, select them and press alt S

Comment: i made my model way too big and had to scale the rig. i tried scaling the model instead but it did the same thing

Comment: Haven't you scaled your bones in Pose mode? You should have done it in Object or Edit mode. Anyway, you can press alt S in Pose mode, then come back to Edit mode and then scale the bones.

Comment: i pressed alt s is pose mode and it scaled it down. i went into edit mode and scaled it back up. it still is making the model huge.

Comment: could you please share your file (or at least a part)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: its not letting me on that site.